# How can i rotate the player according to mouse cursor position clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
  MovePlayer();
}
```

Then the first original MovePlayer i did rotate the player but in the specific angle i set for example:

```
private void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            targetAngles = transform.eulerAngles + 85.0f * Vector3.up;
            StartCoroutine(TurnObject(transform, transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
        }
    }
```

But i want it to rotate to the angle of the mouse cursor  position clicked not to walk there or move there only to rotate and face to the mouse cursor  position clicked. So i tried to change the MovePlayer method to this but this is wrong it does nothing:

```
private void MovePlayer()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                startPositon = hit.point;

                targetAngles = transform.eulerAngles + 0 * Vector3.up;
                StartCoroutine(TurnObject(transform, transform.eulerAngles, targetAngles, smooth));
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
IEnumerator TurnObject(Transform ship, Vector3 startAngle, Vector3 endAngle, float smooth)
    {
        float lerpSpeed = 0;
        isSpinning = true;

        while (lerpSpeed < 1)
        {
            ship.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, lerpSpeed);
            lerpSpeed += Time.deltaTime * smooth;
            yield return null;
        }
        startPositon = ship.position;
        isSpinning = false;
    }
```

This is working but with some problems:

```
void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100000))
        {
            transform.LookAt(hit.point);
        }
    }
```

The first problem is when i point the mouse cursor to the sky since it's too far the player is not rotating and then when i point back to something in the distance range the player jump to the position. Not sure how to solve it. Maybe to calculate the sky(sky box in my case) distance so it will rotate also when pointing the sky ?

The second problem is when i point the mouse cursor on my self the player body it's making some fast rotations on place. How can i avoid it ? Or solve it ?

I tried to change the line:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100000))
```

To

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
```

But it didn't solve it. Maybe the problem is that my sky is a skybox i dragged to the Scene window so it's not an object.

My skybox is material i dragged to the Scene window so maybe this is the problem i can't rotate the player when the mouse cursor is pointing the sky. Any solution?

Comment: Are you working with a first person camera, third person camera, bird's eye camera, or...?

Comment: @Abion47 ThirdPersonController is my player and the main camera is just position behind the player but it's not child of the player it's in the general hierarchy.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem when moving the mouse on my self on the player. I just added this line before the LookAt line: if (hit.collider.name != "ThirdPersonController") now i have to solve the problem with the sky.